# Remove the values ​after the decimal point in the dataframe - regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

After entering:

```
df["column name"].unique()
```

the column has such values:

```
array(['A','B','C','D','D,A,C','B,A'],
dtype=object)
```

I would like to remove all the values ​​after the decimal point and leave something like this:

```
array(['A','B','C','D','D','B'],
dtype=object)
```

that is, remove all values ​​after the decimal point and leave only the first value.

I try:

```
df["col name"] = df["col name"].astype(str).str.replace(r',\d+$', '')
```

but it does not work for me.

Comment: `array(['A','B','C','D','D,A,C','B,A'],` do you have a decimal point or decimal dot? Are those strings consisted of digits or letters?

Comment: Try `df['col name'] = df['col name].str.split(',').str[0]`

Comment: @mrzasa numbers and letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have CSV strings of *letters*, not numbers, but in any case if you just want to strip off everything after (and including) the first comma, then perhaps just try replacing `,.*$` with empty string:

```
df["col name"] = df["col name"].astype(str).str.replace(r',.*$', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension combined with the `split()` function :

```
df["col name"] = [ x.split(',')[0] for x in df["col name"] ]
```

Comment: If you're only interested in the first value, `partition` is preferable to `split`

Answer (score 1):

you could use `extract`

```
df['col name'] = df['col name'].str.extract(r'([A-Z]*)')
```